# Sharepoint Workflow Manager Backend Service crashing

Tags: 2013, workflow, workflow-manager

Workflow manager backend service is crashing on our App server and restarting automatically on Production environment. Due to this all workflows have stopped working. Our workflow farm only has 1 server i.e. App server. Below are event viewer logs from App server. Any help will be appreciated!

```
Log Name:      Microsoft-Workflow/Operational
Source:        Microsoft-Workflow
Date:          12/23/2016 5:45:38 PM
Event ID:      359
Task Category: (65175)
Level:         Critical
Keywords:      Dispatcher
User:          domain\username
Computer:      myappserver
Description:
Dispatcher failfast is causing the Workflow Manager backend to terminate. Exception: System.AggregateException: The dispatcher failure rate has reached 11%. InnerException is the last failure; see traces for other failures. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object . '��e7-3b�g7@
Action' contains invalid UTF8 bytes. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: '��e7-3b�g7@
Action' contains invalid UTF8 bytes. ---> System.Text.DecoderFallbackException: Unable to translate bytes [8C] at index 0 from specified code page to Unicode.
   at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Throw(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.DecoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Byte[] bytes, Byte* pBytes, Char*& chars)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.FallbackInvalidByteSequence(Byte*& pSrc, Int32 ch, DecoderFallbackBuffer fallback, Char*& pTarget)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetChars(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Char* chars, Int32 charCount, DecoderNLS baseDecoder)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32 byteCount, Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex)
   at System.Xml.XmlConverter.ToChars(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Char[] chars, Int32 charOffset)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.XmlConverter.ToChars(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Char[] chars, Int32 charOffset)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.GetChars(Int32 offset, Int32 length, Char[] chars)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.ReadUTF8String(Int32 length)
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.ReadElementContentAsString()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator.ReadElementContentAsGuid()
   at ReadDeferredMessageContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at ReadArrayOfDeferredMessageContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at ReadArrayOfDeferredMessageContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at ReadWorkflowSessionStateFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.WorkflowSessionSerializer.DeserializeWorkflowSessionState(Stream stateStream)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.MessageSessionContext.get_SessionState()
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.SessionAccepted(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.Isolate(AsyncCompletion callback, IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.ExceptionHandlingFrame(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object . '��e7-3b�g7@
Action' contains invalid UTF8 bytes. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: '��e7-3b�g7@
Action' contains invalid UTF8 bytes. ---> System.Text.DecoderFallbackException: Unable to translate bytes [8C] at index 0 from specified code page to Unicode.
   at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Throw(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.DecoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Byte[] bytes, Byte* pBytes, Char*& chars)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.FallbackInvalidByteSequence(Byte*& pSrc, Int32 ch, DecoderFallbackBuffer fallback, Char*& pTarget)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetChars(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Char* chars, Int32 charCount, DecoderNLS baseDecoder)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32 byteCount, Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex)
   at System.Xml.XmlConverter.ToChars(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Char[] chars, Int32 charOffset)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.XmlConverter.ToChars(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Char[] chars, Int32 charOffset)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.GetChars(Int32 offset, Int32 length, Char[] chars)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.ReadUTF8String(Int32 length)
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.ReadElementContentAsString()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator.ReadElementContentAsGuid()
   at ReadDeferredMessageContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at ReadArrayOfDeferredMessageContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at ReadArrayOfDeferredMessageContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at ReadWorkflowSessionStateFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.WorkflowSessionSerializer.DeserializeWorkflowSessionState(Stream stateStream)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.MessageSessionContext.get_SessionState()
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.SessionAccepted(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.Isolate(AsyncCompletion callback, IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.ExceptionHandlingFrame(IAsyncResult result)<---

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name='Microsoft-Workflow' Guid='{B2885F6E-231C-43FF-BBEA-7516148FF6FE}'/><EventID>359</EventID><Version>0</Version><Level>1</Level><Task>65175</Task><Opcode>0</Opcode><Keywords>0x4000000000000200</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2016-12-23T12:15:38.946202700Z'/><EventRecordID>1297494</EventRecordID><Correlation ActivityID='{1FF74906-1A7B-E78F-ACA3-01EEACDB5552}'/><Execution ProcessID='35464' ThreadID='33948'/><Channel>Microsoft-Workflow/Operational</Channel><Computer>myappserver</Computer><Security UserID='S-1-5-21-3992659721-1214000320-2372793640-276999'/></System><EventData><Data Name='exception'>System.AggregateException: The dispatcher failure rate has reached 11%. InnerException is the last failure; see traces for other failures. ---&gt; System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object . '��e7-3b�g7@
Action' contains invalid UTF8 bytes. ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: '��e7-3b�g7@
Action' contains invalid UTF8 bytes. ---&gt; System.Text.DecoderFallbackException: Unable to translate bytes [8C] at index 0 from specified code page to Unicode.
   at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Throw(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.DecoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Byte[] bytes, Byte* pBytes, Char*&amp; chars)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.FallbackInvalidByteSequence(Byte*&amp; pSrc, Int32 ch, DecoderFallbackBuffer fallback, Char*&amp; pTarget)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetChars(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Char* chars, Int32 charCount, DecoderNLS baseDecoder)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32 byteCount, Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex)
   at System.Xml.XmlConverter.ToChars(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Char[] chars, Int32 charOffset)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.XmlConverter.ToChars(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Char[] chars, Int32 charOffset)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.GetChars(Int32 offset, Int32 length, Char[] chars)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.ReadUTF8String(Int32 length)
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.ReadElementContentAsString()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator.ReadElementContentAsGuid()
   at ReadDeferredMessageContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at ReadArrayOfDeferredMessageContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at ReadArrayOfDeferredMessageContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at ReadWorkflowSessionStateFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.WorkflowSessionSerializer.DeserializeWorkflowSessionState(Stream stateStream)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.MessageSessionContext.get_SessionState()
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.SessionAccepted(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.Isolate(AsyncCompletion callback, IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.ExceptionHandlingFrame(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---&gt; (Inner Exception #0) System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object . '��e7-3b�g7@
Action' contains invalid UTF8 bytes. ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: '��e7-3b�g7@
Action' contains invalid UTF8 bytes. ---&gt; System.Text.DecoderFallbackException: Unable to translate bytes [8C] at index 0 from specified code page to Unicode.
   at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Throw(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.DecoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Byte[] bytes, Byte* pBytes, Char*&amp; chars)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.FallbackInvalidByteSequence(Byte*&amp; pSrc, Int32 ch, DecoderFallbackBuffer fallback, Char*&amp; pTarget)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetChars(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Char* chars, Int32 charCount, DecoderNLS baseDecoder)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32 byteCount, Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex)
   at System.Xml.XmlConverter.ToChars(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Char[] chars, Int32 charOffset)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.XmlConverter.ToChars(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Char[] chars, Int32 charOffset)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.GetChars(Int32 offset, Int32 length, Char[] chars)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.ReadUTF8String(Int32 length)
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.ReadElementContentAsString()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator.ReadElementContentAsGuid()
   at ReadDeferredMessageContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at ReadArrayOfDeferredMessageContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at ReadArrayOfDeferredMessageContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at ReadWorkflowSessionStateFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.WorkflowSessionSerializer.DeserializeWorkflowSessionState(Stream stateStream)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.MessageSessionContext.get_SessionState()
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.SessionAccepted(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.Isolate(AsyncCompletion callback, IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.ExceptionHandlingFrame(IAsyncResult result)&lt;---
</Data></EventData></Event>



Log Name:      Microsoft-Workflow/Operational
Source:        Microsoft-Workflow
Date:          12/23/2016 5:45:37 PM
Event ID:      358
Task Category: (65176)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Dispatcher
User:          domain\username
Computer:      myappserver
Description:
Dispatcher encountered an unexpected exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object . '�22c0b�@Ac�eContext?' contains invalid UTF8 bytes. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: '�22c0b�@Ac�eContext?' contains invalid UTF8 bytes. ---> System.Text.DecoderFallbackException: Unable to translate bytes [8C] at index 0 from specified code page to Unicode.
   at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Throw(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.DecoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Byte[] bytes, Byte* pBytes, Char*& chars)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.FallbackInvalidByteSequence(Byte*& pSrc, Int32 ch, DecoderFallbackBuffer fallback, Char*& pTarget)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetChars(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Char* chars, Int32 charCount, DecoderNLS baseDecoder)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32 byteCount, Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex)
   at System.Xml.XmlConverter.ToChars(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Char[] chars, Int32 charOffset)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.XmlConverter.ToChars(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Char[] chars, Int32 charOffset)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.GetChars(Int32 offset, Int32 length, Char[] chars)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.ReadUTF8String(Int32 length)
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.ReadElementContentAsString()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator.ReadElementContentAsGuid()
   at ReadDeferredMessageContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at ReadArrayOfDeferredMessageContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at ReadArrayOfDeferredMessageContextFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at ReadWorkflowSessionStateFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.WorkflowSessionSerializer.DeserializeWorkflowSessionState(Stream stateStream)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.MessageSessionContext.get_SessionState()
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.SessionAccepted(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.Isolate(AsyncCompletion callback, IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.ExceptionHandlingFrame(IAsyncResult result)
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name='Microsoft-Workflow' Guid='{B2885F6E-231C-43FF-BBEA-7516148FF6FE}'/><EventID>358</EventID><Version>0</Version><Level>2</Level><Task>65176</Task><Opcode>0</Opcode><Keywords>0x4000000000000200</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2016-12-23T12:15:37.526548900Z'/><EventRecordID>1297488</EventRecordID><Correlation ActivityID='{C2D42844-AB45-30A6-9A89-9ABE6097AF17}'/><Execution ProcessID='35464' ThreadID='33948'/><Channel>Microsoft-Workflow/Operational</Channel><Computer>PASPRDAPP01.abgplanet.abg.com</Computer><Security UserID='S-1-5-21-3992659721-1214000320-2372793640-276999'/></System><EventData><Data Name='exception'>System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object . '�22c0b�@Ac�eContext?' contains invalid UTF8 bytes. ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: '�22c0b�@Ac�eContext?' contains invalid UTF8 bytes. ---&gt; System.Text.DecoderFallbackException: Unable to translate bytes [8C] at index 0 from specified code page to Unicode.
```

Comment: Did you install any updates(cu) in the sharepoint farm?

Comment: Yes, 2 months ago, we applied July CU update. Our configuration database version: is 15.0.4841.1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates could an issue check this

> It is important that any Cumulative Updates (CU) for SharePoint Server
>   2013 and Workflow Manager are installed in a coordinated fashion.
>   After an update has been performed, several Windows PowerShell cmdlets
>   must be run in order to maintain the connection between the SharePoint
>   Server 2013 farm and the Workflow Manager farm.

Run the following command

```
$credential = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$site = Get-SPSite(<siteUri>)
$proxy = Get-SPWorkflowServiceApplicationProxy
$svcAddress = $proxy.GetWorkflowServiceAddress($site)
Copy-SPActivitiesToWorkflowService -WorkflowServiceAddress $svcAddress -Credential $credential -Force $true
```

Read more here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133867(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: We had just updated SharePoint CU. Is it also necessary to update Workflow Manager and Workflow Manager Client?

Comment: What level of wfm is at, cu 2 or cu 3? I would try to run it after sp updates as wfm updates are rare.

Comment: sorry for late reply. Its on CU 1

Comment: WFM and Service Bus both are 1.0

Comment: Microsoft support engineer has suggested to update WFM to CU 3. We're doing this now, will keep you updated

Comment: I would recommend same as there are many fix in cu3.

Comment: Resolved! Updated service bus gateway and wfm CU 3. Errors from wfm have gone completely. Newly started workflows are working properly. However existing workflow instance are stuck. Interim solution we got from MS is to manually end them and start again. We're planning to write a script to do this

Comment: Great. Touching to each workflow is little pain if we have tons